# How to search by drop down list in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm use ASP.NET MVC. I have a `Student` table in SQL Server and I want to do (search by) name and search by grade in student view by using dropdown list. The problem is the search is not working - when I click on search button, it only refreshes the page with all students.

This is the student controller code

```
public ActionResult Index(string searching, string searchby, int? page)
{
    var student = db.Supervisors;

    if(searchby == "Name")
        return View(student.Where(x => x.name.Contains(searching) || searching == null).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 8));
    else
        return View(student.Where(x => x.grade.Contains(searching) || searching == null).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 8));
}
```

This is the razor code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "student",FormMethod.Get))
{
        @Html.DropDownList("Searchby", new SelectList(new[] { "Name", "Grade" }))
        @Html.TextBox("search")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Comment: You need to bind the model to the view

Comment: What HTML is generated by that Razor @Rawan? Please include that in your post.

Comment: What HTML is generated by that Razor? I'm only write Razor and controller code

Comment: `searching` is *null*.  Make it not null, or remove that part of the query.

Comment: There is nothing in your form that submits a value that binds to your `searching` paramater so its always `null`. Your textbox is named `search`, not `searching`.

Comment: `I'm only write Razor and controller code` When you load it in a browser, the browser loads HTML. Do `View source` in your browser. Then we can explain why you are experiencing the issue. _To be clear, I **know** what the HTML will look like. I am trying to teach you to fish, step by step._

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your form that submits a value that binds to your searching paramater so its always null. Your textbox is named search, not searching

just i changed search to searching

```
    @Html.TextBox("searching")
```